Telescopic cascode amplifier design

I was following a tutorial from youtube and learning about double ended telescopic cascode 2 stage amplifiers. I was curious to know how to modify this circuit to get single ended zwo stage telescopic cascode amplifier.
If possible, please explain the reasoning and share a circuit for the above.

Rohit Rajput - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, public & legal, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/video/etc name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. (More rules in [tour] & [help].)

What exactly do you mean by "single ended"? Do you mean you want the input to be single-ended, or the output, or both?

output should be singly ended!!!
